# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

Появляется ошибка Too many re-renders если у меня вызывается функция в catch. Вообщем я имитирую поиск на сервере и если у меня возникает ошибка то я хочу выполнить поиск на клиенте. В cath я вызываю setData и вставляю туда filteredArray который выполняет поиск на клиенте. Тут выходит ошибка. Где я пишу код неверно? как исправить?

```js
        const fruitData = [
          { item: "Apple", id: 1 },
          { item: "Blueberry", id: 2 },
          { item: "Grape", id: 3 },
          { item: "Banana", id: 4 }
        ];
    
        const App: React.FC = () => {
          const [termInput, setTermInput] = useState<string>("")
          const [data, setData] = useState<any>(fruitData)
          const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
        }
    
        const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(termInput, 1000);
    
        const visibleItems = (items:{item:string; id:number}[], termInput:string) => {
            if (termInput.length === 0) {
              setData(items)
            }
            return items.filter((item) => {
              return item.item.toLowerCase().includes(termInput.toLowerCase())
            })
          }
          
        const filteredArray = visibleItems(fruitData, termInput)
          
          useEffect(() => {
            if (!debouncedSearchTerm) return;
              if (debouncedSearchTerm.length >= 0) {
                const mockServerSearch = (debouncedSearchTerm: string, fruitData: { item: string; id: number }[]) => {
                  const isError = Math.round(Math.random())`введите сюда код`
                  const visibleItemsServer = (items: { item: string; id: number }[], debouncedSearchTerm: string) => {
                    if (debouncedSearchTerm.length === 0) {
                      return items;
                    }
                    return items.filter((item) => {
                      return item.item.toLowerCase().includes(debouncedSearchTerm.toLowerCase())
                    })
                  }
                  const filteredArrayServer = visibleItemsServer(fruitData, debouncedSearchTerm)
    
                  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setLoading(true)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      if (isError) resolve(filteredArrayServer)
                      else reject(new Error("Server search error"))
                      setLoading(false)
                    }, 2000)
                  })
                }
                mockServerSearch(debouncedSearchTerm, fruitData)
                  .then((filteredArrayServer) => {
                    setData(filteredArrayServer)
                  })
                  .catch(() => {
/*Тут я помещаю filteredArray в setData вместо моего начального состояния data*/
                    setData(filteredArray)
                  })
              }
            
          }, [debouncedSearchTerm])

  const loader = loading ? <Loader /> : null;
  const popup = !loading ? <PopupMenu
/*а тут я data передаю в другой компонент*/
    fruits={data}
    active={isActive}
    setIsActive={setIsActive}
    setSelected={selectItems}
    selected={selected}
  /> : null;

 return (
    <div
      className="app"
    >
      <div className="page">
        <SelectField
          showMenu={showMenu}
          selected={selected}
          active={isActive}
          deleteSelectedItem={deleteSelectedItem}
          termInput={termInput}
          setTermInput={setTermInput}
        />
        {loader}
        {popup}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
    
    /*другой компонент где я вставляю свой отфильтрованный массив*/
    const PopupMenu: React.FC<DataProps> = props => {
      const elements = props.fruits.map((fruit) => {
        const { item, id } = fruit;
        return (
          <div key={id}
            className={itemClassName}
            onClick={() => {
              props.setSelected(item)
            }}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      });
    
      return (
        <div className={className}>
          {elements}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: код нужно приводить в виде кода, а не картинки. Почему в state у тебя `data`, а поиск у тебя сохраняется в filteredArray?

Comment: Немного не понял. Я в filteredArray сохранил вызов функции visibleItems с двумя параметрами - это моя база данных которая сверху и то значения которое я набираю. Я вызываю в cath свой filteredArray, который должен выполнять поиск. Однако если я ввел значения, а потом его удалил у меня не возвращается старый массив. Ошибка у меня выходит в тот момент когда я хочу проверить если у меня мой input value пустой, то я устанавливаю весь первоначальный масив в setData. В этом моменте и происходит ошибка. Скорее всего так нельзя делать?

Comment: Как возвращаться к исходному состоянию React? > Сохранить исходное состояние где-то и потом его вызывать, как реактивная переменная, что бы пересовать?  Но по моему, это не то, что вам нужно. Упростите вопрос и декомпозируйте его. И потом, добавьте код не в картинке. А react лучше вообще залить куда-то на  web.

Comment: ничего не понял из сообщения. Добавь в вопрос [mcve] позволяющий воспроизвести твою проблему. неизвестно что и где ты сейчас используешь, поэтому точно указать причину может быть проблематично. Самое простое - на каждый рендер вызывается visibleItems  выдающий **новый** массив, и так происходит постоянно, так как реакт думает, что все постоянно меняется. Даже если сами элементы остались теми же

Comment: где-то в коде идет зацикливание

Comment: добавь место где ты используешь  `filteredArray`

Comment: что именно ты передаешь в `PopupMenu`? Добавь именно jsx в котором ты используешь `filteredArray`

Comment: @fron321 откуда вы берете функцию `useDebounce`? Если это кастомных хук который вы написали то хотелось бы увидеть полный код этого хука.

Comment: в filteredArray у меня функция vidibleItems которая возвращает отфильтрованный массив. Этот отфильтрованный массив я закидываю в состояние data с помощью setData(filteredArray). Потом эту data я передаю в другой компонент

Comment: убери тут `random`: `const isError = Math.round(Math.random())` иначе ты не можешь быть уверен какой именно код у тебя срабатывает. И попробуй добавить больше логов. В текущем виде, так как невозможно запустить пример, можно только гадать. Проверь с разными значениями `termInput` - падает ли во всех случаях или только в случае пустой строки или в случае если строка не пустая.